# nginx refused to connect node app on ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

i have simple nodejs app running on ec2 instance with nginx configs
when tried to access the app from browser it give me `"ec2-18-223-0-201.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect."`

when trying to curl it from VM
using `curl http://localhost:3000` it works correctly, however when trying `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000` it give me this output

```
Found. Redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

here's my nginx configs

```
upstream test{
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
   server_name ec2-18-223-0-201.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com www.ec2-18-223-0-201.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com;
    location / {

 client_max_body_size 20M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_pass http://test;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that should be clear before the actual problem. Is there in redirect policy in node app that returns below output?

> `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000` it gives me this output
>
> `Found. Redirecting to https://127.0.0.1:3000/` because redirection is
>   expected from Nginx, not from node app.

But I am sure the problem is with Nginx not with Node app as it is able to respond on a local port 3000.

`refused to connect` to connect mean that the server not running at all or the port may disable from the firewall.

Two possible reasons:

1. The Port `80` is not allowed in Security Group of the instance so **allow 80** in the security group of AWS instance.
2. The Nginx is not running. Check the log under `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` and the reason might be the log name of the **DNS** in the sever section.

So therefor two Suggestion for Nginx config

1. update your Nginx config to support long DNS name

`vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add value under `http` section in the config

```
http {
server_names_hash_bucket_size  512;
....
}
```

2. Remove redundent name from the config, its not be the reason but you should remove `server_name ec2-18-223-0-201.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com www.ec2-18-223-0-201.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com;`

Comment: thanks for your reply, i've tried your suggestions, non works, in the security group i have the http, https both attached with custom source (0.0.0.0/0, ::/0)
also updated nginx.conf and the issue remains same

Comment: here's error.log content, only one line
ubuntu@ip-:~$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2019/08/25 09:54:50 [notice] 6104#6104: signal process started

Comment: also when trying to access http, it always redirect me to https!

Comment: Check is there any other config in the nginx redirect also clear browser cache

Comment: Check access log too

Comment: 188.161.55.49 - - [25/Aug/2019:10:32:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 158 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36"

Comment: still same issue :/

Comment: it should not redirect to https. and did you restart Nginx after Nginx config update? do one thing more..open 3000 port for public access and verify if backend working fine

Comment: it's completely weird, yes i've restarted nginx, also opened port 3000 for public, still not working and got the same repsonse, but still from inside VM it's working

Comment: You are running VM inside ec2? If the backends is not working first make it working before nginx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198437/discussion-between-adiii-and-m1m6).